# QTimer singleShot with variables and that can be stopped

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am looking to delay a function in the gui but with parameters involved.
I tried running a lambda on singleShot however creating the QTimer beforehand so I can stop it as well, doesn't seem to work.

in my class **init**

```
self.timer = QTimer(self)
```

Calling the timer:

```
self.timer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.send_message('Hey folks'))
```

I want to be able to call .stop if needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the timer instance you created at all: what you're actually doing is to call the *static* singleShot method, which instantly creates and starts a new singleShot-QTimer, and since there's no refererence to that timer, you cannot stop it.

You should set the singleShot property to the *existing* timer instance:

```
self.timer = QTimer(self)
self.timer.setSingleShot(True)

# alternatively:
self.timer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True)
```

If you need to constantly change the target of the timeout, you can call a general `self.timer.disconnect()` (possibly within a `try` block, in case no connection was made before), and create a reference to the function in order to disconnect it:

```
    try:
        self.timer.timeout.disconnect(self.delayedFunction)
    except:
        pass

    def wrapper():
        self.send_message('Hey folks')
        self.timer.timeout.disconnect(wrapper)

    self.delayedFunction = wrapper
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.delayedFunction)
```